# Python: Given a list of users, I need to write a function, that returns all of user's names and roles in a string with each value labeled

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

Given a list of users, I need to write a function, names_and_roles that returns all of user's names and roles in a string with each value labeled.
For example:

```
users = [
    {
         'name': 'Homer', 
         'role': 'Clerk', 
         'dob': '12/02/1988',
         'admin': False 
    }, 
    {
         'name': 'Lisa', 
         'role': 'Staff', 
         'dob': '01/30/1965',
         'admin': False 
    }, 
    {
         'name': 'Marge', 
         'role': 'Associate', 
         'dob': '09/10/1980',
         'admin': True 
    }
]

names_and_roles(users)

# Name: Homer
# Role: Clerk

# Name: Lisa
# Role: Staff

# Name: Marge
# Role: Associate
```

## I tried

```
for i in users:
    print("# Name: "+i['name'] +'\n'+ "# Role: "+i['role']+'\n')
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using `for` loop?

Comment: This is a lazily formatted homework dump without any own efforts. Not a valid question in the scope of this community.

Comment: `for i in users:
    print("# Name: "+i['name'] +'\n'+ "# Role: "+i['role']+'\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a for loop to loop over the list of users....

```
for i in users:
    print("Name: "+i['name'])
    print("Role: "+i['role'])
```